# Como simular uma tela de maior resolução para verificar o comportamento de um website?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Existe alguma forma de simular uma tela com maior resolução para verificar como um site se comporta? Atualmente utilizo 1440x900 e preciso testar a interface em resoluções maiores.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nos browser *Chrome* e *Firefox* existem opções nas ferramentas de desenvolvimento que já vem nativas com os browsers para trabalhar com resoluções especificas. Abaixo os tutoriais de como ativar tais ferramentas.

---

**Chrome**

No Google Chrome existe no DevTools dele uma opção de Emulador, onde você pode simular diversas características no seu browser.

Para ativar, abra seu DevTools, (pressione <kbd>F12</kbd>, ou clique com botão direito e em inspecionar elemento).

No canto direito superior, tem um simbolo de engrenagem [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui], clique nela e no menu General, tópico Appearance ative a primeira opção "Show 'Emulation' view in console".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feche as opções, em cima no botão a esquerda da engrenagem, que parece com uma lista, clique nele. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No menu inferior que apareceu selecione "Emulation" [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] no tópico "Screen" você poderá configurar os dados da sua resolução desejada e o pixel ratio para que caso sua resolução seja menor fique confortável a visualização mesmo tendo mais pixels que seu monitor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Demonstração da resolução desejada em um browser rodando em resolução nativa Full HD, porém emulando 1440x900, porém mudando a *densidade de pixels* você consegue emular resoluções maiores do que a que está usando:
[image: Demonstração da emulação de resolução do Chrome]

Este recurso foi criado para trabalhar com dispositivos móveis, na [página oficial](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=pt-BR) você poderá obter mais detalhes.

---

**Firefox**

Também é possível emular no firefox, abra o inspetor de código e ative o icone de "Design Responsivo" [image: Icone Design Responsivo] no lado superior direito.

Ou através da sequência de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Windows)

Adicione a resolução desejada no menu superior esquerdo que vai aparecer. O resultado pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: Firefox responsive resolution]

Answer (score 3):

Isto tem algumas soluções dependendo da maquina que você está utilizando.

- Por exemplo, drivers de vídeo da nVídia permitem que você adicione resoluções personalizadas maiores do que a do seu monitor, gerando um scroll horizontal e vertical em todo o desktop.
- Outra possibilidade é conectar um monitor adicional na placa de vídeo (isso funciona para vários tipos de placa e fabricante) e estender a área de trabalho nos dois, na horizontal, ampliando a tela do browser.

A vantagem de usar estes dois primeiros recursos é que simular somente dentro do browser às vezes não corresponde à realidade de uma área de trabalho realmente grande.

- Uma outra possibilidade é usar o zoom dos browsers. Por exemplo, a tecla <kbd>-</kbd> no Opera, ou <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> no Chrome, Iron e similares diminuem o zoom da tela, servindo para alguns tipos de avaliação também.
- Fora isso há sites como o **[View Like Us](http://viewlike.us/)**, que permitem uma simulação de resoluções diferentes da sua.

Provavelmente uma boa avaliação pode misturar mais de uma destas técnicas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o recurso Modo de design adaptável (Ctrl + shift + M) do Firefox no menu Desenvolvedor web, depois é só ir configurando as dimensões de cada elemento usando media queries no CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente utilizar o [Screen Fly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/), este site permite que você teste um site hospedado em diversas resoluções, o bacana é que ele tem as resoluções dos aparelhos. Isso acaba facilitando, assim você sabe em quais aparelhos o seu site está rodando perfeito.

Answer (score 1):

Como algumas respostas estão meio datadas, pois os browser são atualizados com frequência, vou contribuir com uma resposta atualizada sobre as versões mais recentes do Chrome. ***É possível simular resoluções superiores a 4K com facilidade***

Primeiro acesse as ferramentes do desenvolvedor do Chrome, apertando <kbd>F12</kbd> ou <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+i</kbd>. Depois disso localize o botão conforme abaixo, ou aperte <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+m</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso na parte superior, basta observar os quadrados vermelhos, vc pode colocar a resolução que quiser, tanto simulando telas menores, quanto maiores.

Aqui está um teste no site da globo com a resolução 50% maior que a minha tela.

**(vc pode ir clicando nas barras AZUL, VERDE ou LARANJA, para ir simulando os *breakpoints* em `min-width` e `max-width`)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora a visualização em 4K

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS1:** Nessa mesma barra onde vc escolhe a resuloção vc também pode testar a tela com valores diferentes de Pixel Density (DPR: 1x, 2x e 3x). Além de poder "girar" a tela entre `portrait` e `landscape` no último botão da barra.

**OBS2:** Quando vc aumenta o *zoom*, vc está na verdade diminuindo a tela e a largura da tela, então se sua tela tem `1000px` de largura e vc aumenta o *zoom* para 150% na verdade sua tela vai estar em `500px` de largura.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma página com um `iframe` chamando a página que deseja testar.

Coloque nesse `iframe` a `width` e `height` que você precisa.

Talvez tenha maneiras melhores, mas assim você consegue testar. Talvez trabalhando no zoom do browser você consiga um bom teste utilizado o `iframe`.