# Como fazer elementos se ajustarem ao tamanho do texto?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

Estou desenvolvendo um site no qual todas as paginas tem um  com um titulo que varia de tamanho, e neste mesmo titulo tem duas linhas, uma de cada lado do texto que tem que ajustar ao tamanho certo.

Sei que parece confuso, mas para explicar melhor segue uma imagem para vocês entenderem:

[image: imagem]

O meu código:

```css
.promo{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 height:200px;
 background-image:url(http://s0.ejesa.ig.com.br/portal/images/2012-07/1.461037.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 background-position:center center;
}
h1{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}

h1.tit_header{
 width:70%;
 margin:80px 15% 10px 15%;
 color:#FFF;
}

.line_01, .line_02, .line_03{
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
 clear:both;
 font-size:1em;
}

.line_01{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:80%;
 margin:0 10%;
 text-align:center;
}

.text_tit{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:33%;
}

.linhaAzul_box{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:33%;
 height:40px;
}
.linha{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 height:5px;
 background-color:#fff;
 margin-top:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo">
    <h1 class="tit_header">
        <span class="line_01">
            <span class="linhaAzul_box"><span class="linha"></span></span>
            <span class="text_tit">Titulo Grande de Mais</span>
            <span class="linhaAzul_box"><span class="linha"></span></span>
        </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Não está bem claro o que procuras... podes explicar melhor? é isto que queres? -> http://jsfiddle.net/j9nv4v3w/3/

Comment: Quase isso, só que ao invés do texto se ajustar é a linha branca que deve ficar maior ou menos.

Comment: Marcelo dei uma resposta, era isso que procurava?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor solução é usar [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), vai te poupar muito trabalho em ficar calculando o posicionamento interno dos elementos e tornar seu `HTML` mais simples. [Ver navegadores que suportam](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Você pode criar dois elementos `<span>` (um antes e outro depois) da tag onde ficará o título. Ou então adotar uma solução mais elegante utilizando os pseudo-elementos `::after` e `::before` das CSS3 para fazer as linhas, visto que elas não tem relevância para página pois trata somente de algo visual.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}

header {
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGejA.jpg) center center;
    background-size:cover;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10% 10px;
    width: 100%;
    
    /* flexbox */
    display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
  
    /* comportamento: em linha com wrap */
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
  
    /* conteúdo justificado no centro */
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
             justify-content:center;
}

span, h2 {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.line {
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:12px;
    height: 4px;
    width: auto /* tcharam! */
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <span class='line'></span>
    <h2 class='title'>Título pequeno?</h2>
    <span class='line'></span>
</header>
```

O segredo está em não definir a largura dos elementos internos, deixando o calculo na mão da propriedade `flexbox`.

**PS**: Você pode definir os tamanhos tranquilamente, o comportamento vai depender da regra `flex-flow`. No exemplo eu deixei o `width` dos elementos todos com `auto`, supondo que eu tivesse definido meu `<h2>` com `200px` e o tamanho ultrapassasse a largura do `header` o conteúdo interno será quebrado como na imagem seguinte:

[image: créditos: CSS-tricks]

É claro, não confie somente nessa regra. Não sei como está o seu CSS mas chegará em uma resolução pequena que você precisará tratar os *breakpoints* corretamente com `media queries`.

Para provar que o `Flexbox` funciona muito bem, por que não testar um título maior?

```css
/* É o mesmo CSS, minificado */

*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}header{background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFTx9.jpg) center center/cover;height:auto;padding:10% 10px;width:100%;display:-webkit-flex;display:flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;flex-flow:row wrap;-webkit-justify-content:center;justify-content:center}h2,span{-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto}.line{background:#fff;margin-top:12px;height:4px;width:auto}h2{color:#fff;text-align:center}
```

```html
<header>
    <span class='line'></span>
    <h2 class='title'>Olá, você me acha um título muito grande?</h2>
    <span class='line'></span>
</header>
```

---

Execute o bloco de código em tela cheia aqui no SOpt. Se estiver no [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), use o atalho <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> para iniciar o modo de design adaptável e ver como as linhas são posicionadas conforme a tela é redimensionada. No [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) existe uma forma semelhante [explicada nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9278/4808).

Comment: A forma que você fez com o Flexbox me parece mais correto e semântico, realmente era isso que eu precisava, obrigado pelo ajuda e desculpa a demora de resposta estou voltando de ferias agora! obrigado mesmo Renan

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a solução passa por usar `display: table;` e `display: table-cell;` nos descendentes imediatos. Dessa maneira consegues que as céculas dessa "tabela" se adaptem ao tamanho/largura.

Porem isso só por sí não resolve pois entendo que queres a célula central basicamente fixa, do tamanho do conteúdo. Para fazer isso funcionar podes enganar o browser e dizer que as laterais devem ter `50%` da largura e que a célula central deve ter `white-space: nowrap;`. Isso vai impedir quebras de linha e vai forçar as células laterais a dar espaço para o titulo.

Sugiro umas mudanças no CSS:

```
.line_01 {
    display: table;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 10%;
    text-align:center;
}
.line_01 > span {
    display: table-cell;
}
.text_tit {
    padding: 0 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.linhaAzul_box {
    width: 50%;
    height:40px;
}
.linha{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38ucz1ev/

Comment: Sensacional, realmente era isso que eu precisava, obrigado pelo ajuda e desculpa a demora de resposta estou voltando de ferias agora! obrigado mesmo Sergio